# Is there a nodemon equivalent for windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js

So nodejs is now available for windows but is there a service that aids development like [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) that works on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote something simple, please let me know if it works for you.

It's here: [nodemonw](https://github.com/cenanozen/nodemonw)

Comment: Only tested very briefly but seems to work fine! I used the .exe as pretty new to this and didn't understand what the other method was. Thanks a bunch. Wonder why there is not more demand for this?!

Comment: You are welcome. I guess people who develop for nodejs use macosx or linux more than windows.

Comment: Just to chime in - since Node and npm are sweet on windows now - nodemon has been updated to work on windows too - so it's all good :)

Answer (score 1):

[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) is working on windows for me (Windows 8.1 32bit, node v0.10.26). Big thanks to the maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS component installed on your Windows you could try [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) and leverage a few benefits (quoted from wiki):

**Process management.** The iisnode module takes care of lifetime management of node.exe processes making it simple to improve overall reliability. You don’t have to implement infrastructure to start, stop, and monitor the processes.

**Side by side with other content types.** The iisnode module integrates with IIS in a way that allows a single web site to contain a variety of content types. For example, a single site can contain a node.js application, static HTML and JavaScript files, PHP applications, and ASP.NET applications. This enables choosing the best tools for the job at hand as well progressive migration of existing applications.

**Scalability on multi-core servers.** Since node.exe is a single threaded process, it only scales to one CPU core. The iisnode module allows creation of multiple node.exe processes per application and load balances the HTTP traffic between them, therefore enabling full utilization of a server’s CPU capacity without requiring additional infrastructure code from an application developer.

**Integrated debugging.** With iisnode integrated debugging you can debug your node.js application deployed to IIS from a browser running on Windows, Mac, or Linux. You get this support out of the box, no extra configuration or installation is necessary. The solution is designed in a way that is shared hosting, firewall, and proxy friendly. The integrated debugging in iisnode uses node-inspector by Danny Coates.

**Auto-update.** The iisnode module ensures that whenever the node.js application is updated (i.e. the script file has changed), the node.exe processes are recycled. Ongoing requests are allowed to gracefully finish execution using the old version of the application, while all new requests are dispatched to the new version of the app.

**Access to logs over HTTP.** The iisnode module provides access the output of the node.exe process (e.g. generated by console.log calls) via HTTP. This facility is key in helping you debug node.js applications deployed to remote servers.

**Minimal changes to node.js application code.** The iisnode module enables hosting of existing HTTP node.js applications with very minimal changes. Typically all that is required is to change the listed address of the HTTP server to one provided by the iisnode module via the process.env.PORT environment variable.

**Integrated management experience.** The issnode module is fully integrated with IIS configuration system and uses the same tools and mechanism as other IIS components for configuration and maintenance.

**Other IIS benefits.** Port sharing, security, URL rewriting, compression, caching, logging

Answer (score 0):

If you have Node.js 18 or higher installed, you can just use the experimental `--watch` mode instead of nodemon:

```
node --watch index.js
```

It will automatically restart the server for you.